# readLine to Set

Tags: java, set, readline

EDITED:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class y {

    Set<String> setA = new HashSet<String>();

    Set<String> getSetA(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            setA.add(line);

        } 
        br.close();
            Iterator<String> iter = setA.iterator();    
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iter.next());
            }
        return setA;

    }
}
```

I try to read every line of a file into element of the Set. But it seem like only the n line is added into the Set. The println only print out the n line in the whole text what wrong with my code?

Comment: replace the if/else with while

Comment: you should debug. print `line` every time it add to set to be sure how many string has add to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your if with a while.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   setA.add(line);
}
```

and then later

```
Iterator<String> iter = setA.iterator();    
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println(iter.next());
}
```

Comment: no, it doesnt. you should move the iterator declaration (and initialization) above the while, and inside the while you should only have while (uter.hasNext())...answer edited to fix that as well